# How does recursion works in a binary search tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Binary search tree algorithms usually use recursion, and I'm having a hard time with it.

This is a code which converts the tree into its mirror image .

```
void mirror_image(struct tree* node1)
{
  if (node1==NULL)
    return;

  else
   {
      struct tree *temp;
      mirror_image(node1->left);
      mirror_image(node1->right);

       temp=node1->left;
       node1->left=node1->right;
       node1->right=temp;

    }

}
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are creating new tree with changing its right and left node. pointers because you are making changes in adresses. first you are assigning value of left node to temp pointer variable. Then value of right node into left node. And at last the value in temp is shifting to right node. its like swapping.

Answer (score 0):

So, it scans the left childs trees using

`mirror_image(node1->left);`

and right childs tress using

`mirror_image(node1->right);`

on reaching the end when

```
if (node1==NULL)
    return;
```

it interchanges them using the swap procedure:

```
temp=node1->left;
node1->left=node1->right;
node1->right=temp;
```

I'd suggest try with a small binary tree, see it yourself on paper.